# Excel VBA Find value in column, and do math

Tags: vba, excel

I have

Column A - with Names
       Column B - with Quantities
       Column C - Where I want returned Value of Quantity x Cost
       Column E - with Names but located in different cells
       Column F - with Prices

What I'm trying to achieve is:  Take value from **A1** and find it in **E:E** (Lets say we found it in **E10**), when found take value of **B1** and multiply it by Respective value of **F10** - and put all this in **Column C**

And so on for all values in **column A**

I was trying to do it with    Do while  and two variables x and y, but for some reason it doesn't find all values only for some rows.

Thank you in Advance.

```
Sub update_button()
'calculates money value for amazon sku
Dim x, y, z As Integer 'x, y, and z variables function as loop counters

'Loop through added SKU/Prices
For x = 4 To 25000
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & x) = "" Then
'Blank row found, exit the loop
Exit For
End If


  'Loop through Column E to find the first blank row to add the value from H into
For y = 4 To 25000
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & y) = "" Then
    'Blank row found, Add SKU and Price
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & y) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & x)
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & y) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & x)

    'Blank out Columns H and I to prevent need to do it manually
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & x) = ""
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & x) = ""
    Exit For
    End If
Next y
Next x

'---NOW THIS IS WHERE I HAVE THE PROBLEM



'Get Values
Dim intCumulativePrice As Integer
'Loop through report tab and get SKU
x = 4 'initialize x to the first row of data on the Sheet1 tab
Do While Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & x) <> "" 'Loop through valid SKU's to find price of item

y = 4 'initialize y to the first row of SKUs on the Sheet1 tab
Do While Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & y) <> ""
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & x) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & y) Then 'Check if current SKU on Sheet1 tab matches the current SKU from SKU list



    'Calculates the total
    intCumulativePrice = intCumulativePrice + (Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & y) * Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & x))
     ' Puts Quantity X Price in Column B agains every Cell
     Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & y) = (Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & y) * Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & x))
Exit Do
End If

y = y + 1
Loop
x = x + 1
Loop
'Puts Grand total in Column L Cell 4
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L4") = intCumulativePrice

'Show messagebox to show that report processing has completed
MsgBox "Report processing has been completed successfully", vbInformation, "Processing Complete!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Can we create a column E with the new values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with VBA you should copy the source data to Variant arrays and loop over those.  Much faster and IMO easier to read and debug.

Something like this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim Dat As Variant
    Dim PriceList As Range
    Dim PriceListNames As Variant
    Dim PriceListPrices As Variant
    Dim Res As Variant
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim nm As String
    Dim nmIdx As Variant
    Dim FirstDataRow As Long

    FirstDataRow = 4
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    With sh
        Dat = Range(.Cells(FirstDataRow, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

        Set PriceList = Range(.Cells(FirstDataRow, "E"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
        PriceListNames = Application.Transpose(PriceList.Columns(1)) ' Need a 1D array for Match
        PriceListPrices = PriceList.Columns(2)

        ReDim Res(1 To UBound(Dat, 1), 1 To 1)
        For i = 1 To UBound(Dat, 1)
            nm = Dat(i, 1)
            nmIdx = Application.Match(nm, PriceListNames, 0)
            If Not IsError(nmIdx) Then
                Res(i, 1) = Dat(i, 2) * PriceListPrices(nmIdx, 1)
            End If
        Next

        Range(.Cells(FirstDataRow, 3), .Cells(UBound(Dat, 1) + FirstDataRow - 1, 3)) = Res
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a simple `VLOOKUP` formula in column C.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,E1:F65000,2,FALSE)*B1
```

You can also use a named range for the data in columns E and F, so you don't have to rely on a fixed address like `E1:F65000`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub HTH()

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range("A4", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Offset(, 2)
            .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A4,E:F,2,FALSE)*$B$1"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```